# Can not compile when using the SwiftyJSON in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I would like to add SwiftyJSON to my app.

I install it using the terminal and create a Podfile in the same folder.

I follow all the steps on[SwiftyJSON on github](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). When I compile the xcode, it turns out the error:

[image]

It seems that I did not have a module called `SwiftyJSON.modulemap`.

What's wrong with that?

Comment: which Xcode version use??

Comment: instead of using SwiftyJson u can use Alamofire it works great !

Comment: install latest version of swiftyjson

Comment: In pod file write pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3' and install pod

Comment: Thanks @shantha.kumar. 
I think the reason I use the swiftyJSON because I just want to parse the data in local, not network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are working in swift 2.3 the pod is:

pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.4'

This is the pod that working properly.